# Rails logger format string configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

How can I configure the rails logger to output its log strings in another format? I would like to get something that is more informative like:

[Log Level] [Time] [Message]

Debug : 01-20-2008 13:11:03.00 : Method Called

This would really help me when I want to tail my development.log for messages that only come from a certain log level, like debug.

Comment: why not use Log4r?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664136/how-to-configure-log4r-with-rails-3-0-x

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Did some digging and found [this](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/9da4250f2c7e2cd7/d6948f578149f2f0?lnk=gst&q=logger#d6948f578149f2f0) post in the RubyOnRails Talk google group.

So I modified it a little bit and put it at the end of my environment.rb:

```
module ActiveSupport
  class BufferedLogger
    def add(severity, message = nil, progname = nil, &block)
      return if @level > severity
      message = (message || (block && block.call) || progname).to_s

      level = {
        0 => "DEBUG",
        1 => "INFO",
        2 => "WARN",
        3 => "ERROR",
        4 => "FATAL"
      }[severity] || "U"

      message = "[%s: %s #%d] %s" % [level,
                                     Time.now.strftime("%m%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                     $$,
                                     message]

      message = "#{message}\n" unless message[-1] == ?\n
      buffer << message
      auto_flush
      message
    end
  end
end
```

This results in a format string like this:

[DEBUG: 0121 10:35:26 #57078] Rendered layouts/_header (0.00089)

Comment: Just to add: a cleaner way to add this patch to your application is to put the code in an initializer.  Just create a file monkey_patching_logger_to_write_date_time.rb and add it in the config/initializers directory, restart your app.

Comment: I had this in my initializer - worked for 3.1, but does not for 3.2 - presumably logging has changed now.

Comment: In 3.2 Rails switched to using ActiveSupport::TaggedLogger.  You can set config.log_tags in your environment.rb that specifies what prefixes to use (e.g., config.log_tags = [ :uuid, :remote_ip, Time.now ]).  I haven't figured out how to include log level yet though.

Comment: throws *** Exception NameError in Class (undefined local variable or method `buffer' for #<ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger:0x11032fb20>) (process 13047, thread #<Thread:0x10d689260>) for rails 3.2.3

Comment: For high-performance environments I'd recommend adding %L for milliseconds to the strftime call.

Comment: Will this work with Rails4?  I'm surprised its not easier to customize the default logging.

Answer (score 2):

For rails 4 apps, I've put together a simple gem that not only adds support for basic tagging like time stamp and log level, but even adds color to the log messages themselves.

https://github.com/phallguy/shog

Answer (score 2):

```
# config/initializers/rack_logger.rb
module Rails
  module Rack
    class Logger < ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber
      # Add UserAgent
      def started_request_message(request)
         'Started %s "%s" for %s at %s by %s' % [
          request.request_method,
          request.filtered_path,
          request.ip,
          Time.now.to_default_s,
          request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

[source link](http://yuumi3.hatenablog.com/entry/20140718/1405643069)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with tags is that they clutter your logs to the point where they are unreadable.

I'd recommend something like [timber](https://github.com/timberio/timber-ruby). It automatically augments your logs with context (level, time, session id, etc) without sacrificing readability.