# What's a good logging replacement for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

So, I've been looking into logging in my Rails app and I'm discovering, thanks to posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462651/rails-logger-format-string-configuration), that the default Rails logging format is terrible and there isn't an easy way to change it. Can anyone recommend a simple replacement for the default logger?

**Bonus question:** Is there a stated reason for *why* it's so hard to change the default format in BufferedLogger?

Comment: The approach in the accepted answer in the question you linked doesn't seem *that* hard.

Comment: Not so much hard as awkward. I suppose this question is born more out of frustration that the standard Rails logger is surprisingly sub-par, given that Rails generally goes out of its way to make things easier for you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I beg to differ. Rails spoils us in a number of ways and to be asked to monkey-patch a class I've never heard of, just to get rid of some extra whitespace I never asked for, seems pretty out of character for the framework. So it's definitely worth while to ask why this is the case.