# How to see request user-agent in Heroku logs

Tags: heroku, user-agent

I have a Heroku app where I want to see the user-agent clients are using for their requests.  When I do:

```
hk logs --app myapp
```

I see lots of interesting info, but not the HTTP request headers or the User-Agent.  Is there a way to get these, or is there a way to tell Heroku to log these for future requests?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to log specific request details to rails server logs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267540/how-to-log-specific-request-details-to-rails-server-logs)

Comment: I'm afraid that you will have to log this on your own. Heroku [has specified](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-router-log-format) what is logged by default and there is no reference how to edit this.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/simonw/1e0fdf2e9b8744b39bd7

Answer (score 1):

To customize logs messages you will have to implement specific logger in your application, like @RobinGower suggests in comments to your question. It's not a common task, so there is no 1-click solutions for this.

Though if you have common goal for why you want to see user-agent - solution could be easy, for example:

- if you want to see for which browsers some specific error happens, you can use "rollbar" or simialr error logging heroku's extension

[image]

- if you want to do some calculations on which browsers used to reach different pages, you may be interested in embedding to you application analytics system, like "Google analytics":

[image]