# Better way to format log messages in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I found this.  It seems kind of ugly to just throw this into environment.rb.  The question is kind of old.  I just wanted to ask if there was a better way to do this now.

The problem (if you don't want to click through), is including your custom log message formatter.  (The problem I'm solving is that I want to assign a guid to every request, prepend all log messages from that request with the guid, and then return the guid in meta data to the client a.k.a. request id)

[Rails logger format string configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462651/rails-logger-format-string-configuration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it in an **initializer**.

Initializers can be any name and go in `config/initializers`. Every file in this directory is loaded at startup; it's a great place to put miscellaneous startup code that doesn't seem to fit anywhere else.

Comment: thanks, pretty much this is what I was looking for.  Much cleaner.