# How to direct Unicorn stdout and stderr to log4r logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging, unicorn, log4r

I have set up `log4r` as per outlined here: "[How to configure Log4r with Rails 3.0.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664136/how-to-configure-log4r-with-rails-3-0-x)"

However now I'm faced with unicorn not sending its output to the log4r logs. How do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

does this comment help?

> in your config, Rails isn't overriding the "file" config value of the
>   outputter - the argument is "filename" :) It defaults to the name of
>   the file/command that started the process. Note that any custom file
>   name you specify must have a file extension, or it will fail to stick
>   the date in the file name! – Nevir Aug 24 '11 at 22:05