# Rails development log file - time of writing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

In my Rails project, I noticed that sometimes actions are not written into the log file `development.log` immediately after they are done, but rather after some other actions are done (or maybe just after some amount of time, I'm not sure.) Exactly when is the `development.log` file written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Updated for Rails 3.2

<strike>The default logging for Rails is buffered, so log message are not written immediately, but happen in batches. You can force the logger to flush the buffer with:</strike>

That was the old way, [as of 3.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html) the filesystem handles buffering before writing the log:

> ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger#auto_flushing is deprecated. Either set
>   the sync level on the underlying file handle like this. Or tune your
>   filesystem. The FS cache is now what controls flushing.

You can change your *config/environments/development.rb* to auto flush with every log message:

```
config.autoflush_log = true
```

This is used by [bootstrap.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb) to force the sync of the log (*e.g.* `f.sync = true`). This will noticeable impact performance.

Comment: Hmm I see.. so what is the default auto-flush period? How many messages must pile up before the logger flushes?

Comment: This has changed as of 3.2, the file system controls when the log is flushed to the file.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use log4r?

1. it is very fast
2. it supports the timestamp
3. you can customize the output format as you wish.

for usage, please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5959013/445908