# Finding out cause of slow Rails request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm seeing a very slow request on a create action in the controller (all other actions are within acceptable limits). Tailing the logs shows me that views and activerecord, while not the fastest, are only a fraction of the total load time. Here's what I see:

```
Completed 200 OK in 37023ms (Views: 530.1ms | ActiveRecord: 251.2ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)
```

Is there a way to see where the remainder of the time is spent? I've tried Mini Profiler, but it isn't showing me where that time is spent.

To add a bit of additional context, the model (Story) has a has_many :through that joins it to the User model. It appears that the slowdown only occurs when users are assigned to the story. If no users are selected, the response time is fine. Could the issue be missing indexes on the join model?

Answer (score 0):

One of my practice is adding logs to your action. e.g.

```
def some_action_which_is_very_slow
  logger.debug "== line 1, #{Time.now}"
  # statement 1 
  logger.debug "== line 2, #{Time.now}"
  # statement 2 
  logger.debug "== line 3, #{Time.now}"
  # statement 3
end
```

p.s.  using #{Time.now} is not smart enough. you should configure your log files to support the time format. I suggest using log4r. see this stack post: [How to configure Log4r with Rails 3.0.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664136/how-to-configure-log4r-with-rails-3-0-x)

Answer (score 0):

Use benchmark like this:

```
def some_action
    benchmark 'running queries' do
       # some code for running queries
    end
    benchmark 'some other operation' do
       # some other code
    end
end
```

And you will get the results in developement.log. You can use it in views as well:

```
<% benchmark 'some partial' do %>
    <div>copde here</div>
<% end %>
```