# How to configure log4r 1.1.10 with rails 3.2.13 and ruby 2.0.0 p0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, log4r

I am a newbie to Ruby On Rails and i am struck with configuring logging for the application which i am developing

I followed the steps answered in this question [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664136/how-to-configure-log4r-with-rails-3-0-x)

In my log directory, the log file gets created. But nothing gets written to the log file.

I am using ruby 2.0.0 p0.  How to debug and fix this?   I am struck on this for a day.

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed. I was having 
Rails.logger = Log4r::Logger.new("Application Log")
in my environment.rb file.

Once i removed it, logging worked fine.