# rails6 log4r tagged_logging.rb:22:in `call': wrong number of arguments

Tags: log4r, ruby-on-rails-6

When I use log4r in rails 6, I report the following error

This is the complete error information

```
.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `call': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 4) (ArgumentError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### config/initializers/log4r_patch.rb

```rb
class Log4r::Logger
  def formatter()
    Proc.new{|severity, time, progname, msg|
      formatted_severity = sprintf("%-5s",severity.to_s)
      formatted_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      "[#{formatted_severity} #{formatted_time} #{$$}]\n #{msg}\n"
    }
  end
  def formatter=(temp)
  end
end
```

refer to: https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/building-a-custom-logger-in-rails/