# Is this possible to change rails logs messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

Standard start of rails log message is like this:

```
Started GET "/newrelic" for 192.168.18.36 at 2013-09-04 15:19:34 +0200
```

But I would like to have something like this:

```
[request_id] Started GET "/newrelic" for 192.168.18.36 at 2013-09-04 15:19:34 +0200
```

Is it possible to achevie this?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462651/rails-logger-format-string-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You can achieve this by using config.log_tags. The log_tags option was added in Rails 3.2 and can be used to prepend information to each log message.

In /config/environments/development.rb

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.log_tags = [:request_id]
  ...
end
```