# How do I remove IP addresses from log in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

For GDPR-reasons I would like to remove IP-addresses in my logs as I have no use of that information, and thus it is not necessary to keep them.

- Rails v 4.2.10
- Ruby v 2.4.7

Is there an easy way of filtering the IP-addresses in the log file or at least replace them? I am specifically interested in this line:

```
Started GET "/" for xx.xxx.xxx.x at 2020-05-11 14:14:30 +0000
```

where xx.xxx.xxx.x is an actual IP number.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705823/disable-ip-address-logging-rails

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned I have checked that one out before. It seems overly complicated and, frankly, I have no idea what it actually does. I would expect something far simpler for a task like this (such as how passwords can be filtered).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can just monkey patch the [logger class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/98a57aa5f610bc66af31af409c72173cdeeb3c9e/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb#L48) so I doesn't append the ip to the log message:

```
module Rails
  module Rack
    class Logger
      def started_request_message(request) # :doc:
        'Started %s "%s" for %s at %s' % [
          request.request_method,
          request.filtered_path,
          'xx.xxx.xxx.x', // request.remote_ip
          Time.now.to_default_s ]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

you can add that to an initializer and that should do the trick.